# POST request in ANDROID

Tags: android

### I want to know how POST request happens in Android

---

**`What I have Tried::`**

- I have done parsing with Get request in android ( I have mentioned the parser class below that i have used )

**`what I have understood from it::`**

- We use the parser class to parse the `JSON response` from the server,
  then use the functionalities of `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` to get the
  data from the JSON response
- Then we use the `Java variable` to store the data and use that java
  variable to populate any `views in android`

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

---

### What I want to know is How a POST request happens and how a post request works ?

**My search in google::**

- According to me we need to store a data to be sent to server as
  `key,value` pair
- add the `key,value` pair to a object
- Send the object to the server
- And someone in the server need to extract the value(data) from the
  object using key and do some processing like a database query

---

**MY Query::**

- PLEASE PROVIDE  MORE CLARITY ON POST_REQUEST
- HOW IT FUNCTIONS
- HOW IT WORKS
- A GOOD EXAMPLE FOR A NEWBIE TO UNDERSTAND

---

*Hope i am clear*

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study something about Http and TCP/IP first.

when you use a GET method,the server will just get information from the incoming URL.But if you make a Post request,the server can fetch data from a InputStream that the request brings(which is the post method's OutputStream).

No matter what request method you have used,the response from the server may be the same.So it means the request just affect the server.